# Django swagger- How to disable DjangoFilterBackend query filters from delete, put methods?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, swagger, django-rest-swagger

I've created an `AssetsFilter` class:

```
from django_filters import Filter
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters
from django_filters.fields import Lookup

from .models import Assets


class MyListFilter(Filter):
    def filter(self, qs, value):
        value_list = value.split(',')
        return super(ListFilter, self).filter(qs, Lookup(value_list, 'in'))


class AssetsFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    name = filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains', help_text=u'Filter by name')
    criticality = MyListFilter(name='critical', help_text=u'Filter by_id')

    class Meta:
        model = Assets
        fields = ['name', 'criticality ']
```

Now I'm using this filter in my Viewset as follows:

```
from .serializers import AssetSerializers
from .filters import AssetsFilter


class AssetViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    This viewset automatically provides `list`, `create`, `retrieve`,
    `update` and `destroy` actions.
    """
    queryset = Assets.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AssetSerializers
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_class = AssetsFilter
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete']

    def list(self, request):
        """
        Returns a list of Asset.
        """
        return super(AssetViewSet, self).list(request)

    def create(self, request):
        """
        Creates a new Asset.<br>
        """
        return super(AssetViewSet, self).create(request)

    def destroy(self, request, pk=None):
        """
        Deletes a Asset.
        """
        return super(AssetViewSet, self).destroy(request, pk=pk)

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        """
        Returns a Asset with id={id}
        """
        return super(AssetViewSet, self).retrieve(request, pk=pk)

    def update(self, request, pk=None, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Updates an existing Asset.<br>
        """
        return super(AssetViewSet, self).update(request, pk=pk, *args, **kwargs)
```

When the swagger documentation is created, the filter fields appear in `GET (list)`, `GET (retrieve)` as expected, but they also appear in the `POST`, `PUT`, `PATCH` and `DELETE` where they shouldn't be.

How can I disable those parameters from appearing in the latest version of django-rest-swagger and DRF?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you don't want to Add Schema Manually(Every time) then Here is the solution:
auto_schema.py

```
from rest_framework.schemas import AutoSchema
from django.utils.six.moves.urllib import parse as urlparse
import coreapi, coreschema


class CustomSchema(AutoSchema):
    def get_link(self, path, method, base_url):
        fields = self.get_path_fields(path, method)
        fields += self.get_serializer_fields(path, method)
        fields += self.get_pagination_fields(path, method)
        if self.view.action in ['list']:
            fields += self.get_filter_fields(path, method)

        manual_fields = self.get_manual_fields(path, method)
        fields = self.update_fields(fields, manual_fields)

        if fields and any([field.location in ('form', 'body') for field in fields]):
            encoding = self.get_encoding(path, method)
        else:
            encoding = None

        description = self.get_description(path, method)

        if base_url and path.startswith('/'):
            path = path[1:]

        return coreapi.Link(
            url=urlparse.urljoin(base_url, path),
            action=method.lower(),
            encoding=encoding,
            fields=fields,
            description=description
        )
```

views.py

```
class MyUserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.

    """
    model = MyUser
    serializer_class = MyUserSerializer
    queryset = MyUser.objects.all()
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, OrderingFilter)
    filter_class = MyUserFilter
    ordering_fields = ('last_name', 'first_name', 'email', 'is_active')
    ordering = ('last_name', 'first_name')
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    schema = CustomSchema()
```

Comment: Thx, i just realize that I can overwrite _allows_filters() in MySchema.

Answer (score 1):

Specifying a CustomSchema for every model is not necessary.
It is possible to override the DjangoFilterBackend and prevent it from adding the schema fields for some specified actions:

```
class MyDjangoFilterBackend(DjangoFilterBackend):
    def get_schema_fields(self, view):
        # Customize according to your need here.
        if view.action not in ["list"]:
            return []
        return super().get_schema_fields(view)
```

in settings.py :

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': (
       'api.filter_backends.MyDjangoFilterBackend'
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'api.pagination.MyPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 20
}
```